# sleep and exercise

Tags: exercise, workout, sleep

I sleep for about 8 hours the other day and just last night I have just about 2 hours of sleep. Can I do light exercise workout later?Or if I sleep about 2 hours later and exercise is that ok?

Comment: Why do need to workout if you only have slept for two hours? Perhaps you can add more context to the question

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option of getting a little more sleep before doing a workout, then that is obviously ideal. If you don't have that option, then it's a judgment call on your part to see weather you feel up to it or not, but regardless it should be a light workout.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be a problem. Getting 2hrs of sleep 1-3 times a month is alright.But, try to aim for 8 hours of sleep always and try to stay consistent.

Take a nap, if you're tired. If you're not tired then go ahead and workout.